# Internationalization, ComponentOrientation and right-to-left

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

I am internationalizing a fairly large Swing application. I've done all the `ResourceBundle` work and next tried right-to-left orientation.

I had expected that simply setting the Locale from the command line (via JVM arguments) would propagate to all instantiated components, but this doesn't appear to be the case. My default Locale is correct (`iw_IL` in my test case) but layouts such as GridBag don't respect the default.

I tried explicitly setting the default in my main method, and then also using `applyComponentOrientation` to my parent JFrame, but this doesn't work either. Applying to a specific JPanel does work (for the GridBag layout) but this doesn't affect child components such as ComboBoxes.

```
public class TestI18N extends JFrame {

TestI18N() {
    super("Test I18N");
    //test 1 - set orientation at instantiation, this just affects the border layout not the menu or combos
    applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(Locale.getDefault()));
    JComponent comp = (JComponent)getContentPane();
    setJMenuBar(getTestMenuBar());
    comp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JComboBox<String> box1 = new JComboBox<String>(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"one", "two", "three"}));
    comp.add(box1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    JComboBox<String> box2 = new JComboBox<String>(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"uno", "dos", "tres"}));
    comp.add(box2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    //test 2 - this orients the menu and combo box arrows
    //but the renderers are still LTR
    applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(Locale.getDefault()));
}

private JMenuBar getTestMenuBar() {
    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    bar.add(new JMenuItem("Menu item"));
    return bar;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("iw", "IL");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    System.out.println("default locale="+Locale.getDefault());
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TestI18N me = new TestI18N();
            me.pack();
            me.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Now without the calls to 'apply', everything is normal (despite the fact that the default Locale is RTL). If I just use the first 'apply', the uno box is on the left but the menu and combos are normal. Using the second 'apply' I get the menu RTL and the combo arrows are on the left, but the data is still left justified. So I guess now the renderer needs to be modified?

Is this the way it is supposed to work? If I was running on a Windows box in Israel, would I still have to do all this?

Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Care to show some code? just to see how you are using applyComponentOrinetation maybe? or an SSCCE demonstrating the problem? (lol @AndrewThompson +1 beat me to it).. Because looking at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/bidi.html#setting-component-orientation) example provided by oracle they say: *Swing's layout managers understand how locale affects a UI; it is not necessary to create a new layout for each locale...* and in turn show a simple: `frame.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(currentLocale));`

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  *"AndrewThompson beat me to it"*  No, ComA did - that is what I call 'Comment Assistant', a little app. I wrote for storing my most common comments.  Type a few letters to narrow it down, hit enter when there is only one shown and it is added to a list of comments that can be used for comments or (rarely) answers.  Very handy..  ;)

Comment: RTL is supported by all LayoutManagers, maybe there is one two bugs in ZOrder, but nobody knows without code in SSCCE form, your effort equals better answers, not only comments